# Reading lines and reversing the text with Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, text, io, functional-programming

My program should do the following:

- Read lines from a file
- For each line, reverse the text of each word ("bat cat hat" becomes "tab tac tah")
- Print out the the reverse text

But it doesn't work and being a Haskell-newbie, I can't understand the errors.

Here is my code:

```
main = do
    content <- readFile "test.txt"
    let linesList = lines content
    reverseLines

reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words

reverseLines :: [String] -> IO ()
reverseLines inputList = do
    if null inputList
        then return ()
        else do
        line <- inputList!!0
        if null line
            then return ()
            else do
                putStrLn $ reverseWords line
                reverseLines . tail inputList
```

And my errors:

```
readlines.hs:4:9:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO b0'
                with actual type `[String] -> IO ()'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: reverseLines
    In the expression:
      do { content <- readFile "test.txt";
           let linesList = lines content;
           reverseLines }
    In an equation for `main':
        main
          = do { content <- readFile "test.txt";
                 let linesList = ...;
                 reverseLines }

readlines.hs:14:25:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `IO [Char]'
    Expected type: [IO [Char]]
      Actual type: [String]
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `inputList'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: line <- inputList !! 0
    In the expression:
      do { line <- inputList !! 0;
           if null line then
               return ()
           else
               do { putStrLn $ reverseWords line;
                    .... } }

readlines.hs:19:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `a0 -> IO ()'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: reverseLines . tail inputList
    In the expression:
      do { putStrLn $ reverseWords line;
           reverseLines . tail inputList }
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      if null line then
          return ()
      else
          do { putStrLn $ reverseWords line;
               reverseLines . tail inputList }

readlines.hs:19:48:
    Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> [String]'
                with actual type `[String]'
    In the return type of a call of `tail'
    Probable cause: `tail' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `tail inputList'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: reverseLines . tail inputList
```

Comment: The first thing you should do when you see a new error message is to read it carefully, then if you can't figure out what it means, do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+Couldn%27t+match+expected+type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your last line in your `main` function is of type [String] -> IO (), and you need it to be IO (), so you actually need to pass it the list of strings. Here is one way to do what you are requesting:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    content <- readFile "test.txt"
    let linesList = lines content
    reverseLines linesList

reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words

reverseLines :: [String] -> IO ()
reverseLines = mapM_ (putStrLn . reverseWords)
```

And here is a recursive version akin to what you wanted to do in your version

```
reverseLines2 :: [String] -> IO ()
reverseLines2 []      = return ()
reverseLines2 (x:xs)  = do
  putStrLn (reverseWords x)
  reverseLines2 xs
```

I've also fixed your version with minimal changes, but bear in mind that this is not really the Haskell way to do things. Go with one of the options I provided above.

```
main = do
    content <- readFile "test.txt"
    let linesList = lines content
    reverseLines linesList

reverseWords :: String -> String
reverseWords = unwords . map reverse . words

reverseLines :: [String] -> IO ()
reverseLines inputList = do
    if null inputList
        then return ()
    else do
      let line = head inputList 
      if null line
          then return ()
          else do
              putStrLn $ reverseWords line
              reverseLines $ tail inputList
```